# R - How to scale/unscale for Keras

Tags: r, keras

I am confused of what to scale for Keras in R.

I have a univariate time series vector `data = [1, 2, 3, ..., 1000]` which I want a LSTM to predict. I split this vector between `train = [1, 2, ..., 997]` and `test = [998, 999, 1000]` vectors. After, I took the train vector and created two sliding window matrices, for training it.

```
X_train, y_train
[1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 4] [5, 6, 7]
[3, 4, 5] [6, 7 ,8]
[4, 5, 6] [7, 8, 9]
[5, 6, 7] [8, 9, 10]
    ...     ...
```

I am confused when to scale. Should I scale my inicial `data = [1, 2, 3, ..., 1000]` vector or should I scale the `train = [1, 2, ..., 997]` and `test = [998, 999, 1000]` vectors separately? Is there any difference in these two approaches?

I want to try two sort of scaling, between -1 and 1 and between 0 and 1.

**EDIT**
My real data lies between -9 and +2

Answer (score 0):

Well, scaling depends on the dataset. If you consider that, you should also consider if you want to use your supervised model to predict new data given only **one** new input at a time or **a batch** of new inputs. A general approach is to apply the scaling "coeficcients" (let's say, max min, or z-score) from the training set to the test set. Because that's one way of making test data look like test data, which is what your model was trained on.

So, being very objective: yes, there is difference between scaling everything and then train/test splitting vs splitting first and then scaling separately. I suggest you read [this question from stats exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117350/how-to-split-dataset-for-time-series-prediction).